# How does the microprocessor make the bits move from memory to inside of it?

Tags: memory, cpu

I was just wondering, since it only fetches bytes that are read as circuit instructions to process data and the like, but how exactly does it "move", get the bits going, outside of the RAM IC to inside of it?

Comment: This question almost doesn't belong here, and instead belongs over on Electrical Engineering.  If you are really interested in this, then you might need to spend a year or two learning digital electronics to understand this in depth.

Comment: on a high level, the cpu contains 'instructions' that allow it to send a request to the memory controller chip to access and send a block of ram over the system bus between the CPU socket and the memory controller. if you want a deeper answer than that, @Zoredache is correct.

Comment: Why do you assumr it would take a year, and why do you assumie I do not know?

Comment: Likely because of the use of vague terms like "circuit instructions" and "get the bits going". Someone who understood the basic concepts that an answer to this question would would use would almost certainly know the common terms for those concepts rather than vaguely describing them.

Answer (score 1):

bits are represented by voltages, it's not a moving thing.

One can measure the voltage at 2 points on a wire.  A printed circuit board(PCB) e.g. a motherboard, has the equivalent of wires, called  "traces"/"conductive pathways".

Parts e.g. CPU and RAM, are connected, directly or indirectly.  I'm not that well read on this, but it used to be a set of wires running in parallel(8 wires would transfer a byte, one bit per wire), now of course, it'd be traces on a circuit board. The connection, often drawn on paper with a line or set of lines, is called a bus.

So you could have CPU(drawn as a square) and RAM(drawn as a square) connected directly with a bus(drawn as a line or set of lines). You could have a chipset(drawn as a square), which CPU and RAM and other devices connect to.   All the devices on the motherboard are connected.

There is a subject called CPU architecture. You have a similar setup inside a CPU, with areas of storage(cpu storage locations are called 'registers'), and internal busses. So it fetches instructions from RAM puts it in a register,  and (at the request of an instruction) fetches data from RAM(via a bus external to the CPU), puts that in registers, and processes the data(according to the instruction) and stores results in registers, and there might be an instruction to write that result to RAM, so that'd be transferred externally(onto a bus external to the CPU).

Old books explain it with terms such as  MAR(memory address register)  MDR(memory data register) aka memory buffer register(MBR),   address bus, data bus, control lines. it's worth looking up. any old computer science book would show it. like lett's pat heathcote a level computer science.